# Importing multiple arrays from a single text file that change every time text is encountered

Tags: python, arrays, file, matrix, text

I have a .txt file called heads.txt which is a matrix of 1.4 million rows (see photo)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLf9a.png). Every 577 rows there is a text string #, #, #, period, timestep, layer. I want to create a new array every time this text string is encountered.

The code I have imports the .txt file and I can come up with some code to skiprow 1 but then my code fails the next time this text line is encountered.

I would eventually like to put each of these arrays into rows and columns.

Please help. This is the code I currently have.

matrix = np.loadtxt('heads.txt', delimiter=",", skiprows=1)

Comment: I would like to create 577 rows by 648 columns

Comment: does skiprows accept lists? `skiprows = [x for x in range(1400000) if x%577==0]`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How does your code fail? Does it throw an exception? Does it complete but produce incorrect output? Please provide more information.

Comment: read the rows one by one, split on the `,` character and assess the length of the list from that last split. Create a new list (array) when the length is 6

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

test if this works for your file

```py
result = []
with open("somefile.txt") as infile:
    curr_list = []
    for line in infile.read().splitlines()[1:]: # skip the first line
        split = line.split(",")
        if len(split) != 6:
            curr_list.append(split)
        else:
            result.append(curr_list)
            curr_list = []
```